# Which of these functions are in the range of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, definite-integrals, continuity, linear-transformations

Let $C[0,1]$ be the vector space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, and let $T: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ be the linear transformation that takes a function $f(x)$ to $\int_0^x f(t) \ dt$. Which of the following functions are in the range of $T$? (Select all that apply.)
Select one or more:

a. $g(x) = x + 1$

b. $g(x) = x^2$

c. $g(x) = \cos x$

d. $g(x) = \sin x$

e. $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x+2}$

I'm confused on how to approach questions with continuous functions, so can I just have a hint or two about how to approach this problem.

Comment: Hint: What does it take for a function to be in the range of $T$? Maybe you can extract this condition from the definition of $T$. Can you share your attempts with this hint? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $f\in C[0,1]$, $T(f)(0)=\int_0^0f(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$. So, that excludes a., c., and e.

Now, concerning b., can you think about some function $f\in C[0,1]$ such that$$(\forall x\in[0,1]):\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=x^2?$$And what about d.?

Comment: For b., we could have $x^3/3$ and for d., we could have $-cos x$, right? What do I do next?

Comment: Wrong. For b. you take $f(t)=2t$ and for d. you take $f(t)=\cos(t)$.

Comment: Oh! I get it now, we're just solving for $f(t)$ by finding the derivative! That makes sense, thanks! Also, for d., shouldn't it be $-cos(t)$, not $cos(t)$?

Comment: So the final answer is b. and d.?

Comment: Yes, the final answer is b. and d. About d., the answer is $\cos$ because$$(\forall x\in[0,1]):T(\cos)(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t)\,\mathrm dt=\sin(x).$$

Comment: Ohhhhh. Ok thanks for the help!!!